# Search a string with last two characters as numeric

Tags: sed, awk

Suppose I have a file like this:

```
adasfddfd09
dsassd90897
323sdsdsdsd
sdddsdf56
dfdf45fdfdf
```

I want to search only those strings which have last two characters numeric with `sed`, `grep` and `awk`.

Comment: `grep '[0-9][0-9]$'`

Comment: I think the edit was wrong, since he has a file with one line, a string with multiple strings.

Comment: do you only want it to end with two numbers or EXACTLY with two numbers and not more?

Comment: @polym, only user130240 can tell us, but if you look at [the question as he posted it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/38b76915-b72a-40e0-b0ee-f82167a14f23/view-source), I strongly suspect those are meant to be one per line.

Answer (score 6):

## Commands for grep and sed

It looks like the original question was formatted incorrectly. Hence, the simplest grep and sed commands are:

```
egrep '[0-9]{2}$' /path/to/file
```

and

```
sed -rn '/[0-9]{2}$/p' /path/to/file
```

I'll leave the explanations below, which include information on these commands, but also work with multiple strings on single lines. They will still work, but include additional, potentially extraneous code.

---

### Grep

```
grep '[^ ]*[0-9]\{2\}( |$)' /path/to/file
```

#### Explanation

- `[^ ]*` Match any number of non-space characters.
- `[0-9]\{2\}` Match two digits. (You could use `[0-9][0-9]` instead.)
- `( |$)` The digits should be the end of a "word", hence should be followed by either a space or an end-of-line terminator.

I prefer using extended grep instead, as you won't need to escape the curly braces. Hence,

```
grep -E '[^ ]*[0-9]{2}( |$)' /path/to/file
```

or

```
egrep '[^ ]*[0-9]{2}( |$)' /path/to/file
```

The question has been edited, but if there are multiple matches on a line, and you want to only output the matches, then use the `-o` flag. i.e.

```
egrep -o '[^ ]*[0-9]{2}( |$)' /path/to/file
```

---

### Sed

```
</path/to/file tr ' ' '\n' | sed -rn '/[0-9]{2}$/p'
```

#### Explanation

- `</path/to/file tr ' ' '\n'` Input file and change all spaces to newlines.
- `sed -rn` Use extended regular expressions (similar to above) with `-r`, and don't print all the output immediately with `-n`.
- `[0-9]{2}$` This regular expression is similar to the one above in the grep line. However, since we've already removed all the spaces, we don't need to define the non-space characters at the beginning, nor the possible space at the end.
- `/<regex>/p` Print out the lines matching `<regex>`.

Comment: Also matches dsassd90897 and only highlights matches, since its grep.

Comment: @polym, I think they want dsassd90897, right? Also, I'm not sure what output they want... and there's since been an edit to the question. Anyway, I've edited for the last part.

Comment: yeah might be. it's a bit unclear. Nice answer though with egrep :)

Comment: This is wrong: `[ $]` -- that looks for a character that is either a space or a dollar sign. You were thinking of `( |$)`

Comment: @Sparhawk reduce the size of `Explanation,Grep,...` headings.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Do you mean font size? I just specified the header 1 and header 2 sizes for sections and sub-sections. What do you suggest?

Comment: Yep, `###` would be enough.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Done. I didn't even know `###` existed. Thanks.

Comment: And +1 from me  :-)

Answer (score 4):

`sed` plus `awk` should do the trick!

```
sed 's/ /\n/g' file1 | awk '/[0-9][0-9]$/'
```

**If** your file contains these strings **line by line** `awk` only should do the trick!

```
awk '/[0-9][0-9]$/' file1
```

**If** you want to match strings that end with **EXACTLY two numbers and *not more***, then use these commands instead:

```
sed 's/ /\n/g' file1 | awk '/[^0-9][0-9][0-9]$/'
```

and

```
awk '/[^0-9][0-9][0-9]$/' file1
```

## Output:

```
adasfddfd09
dsassd90897
sdddsdf56
```

## Explanation

- `sed` splits your input string into multiple strings.
- `awk` matches all strings that end with exactly two numbers.

Comment: Nice edit (I think, but again the question is unclear :). +1 (For the sed part, I think you could do that in awk? I'm also not sure if `tr` would be faster, but probably only marginal if anything.)

Comment: Ha… I was curious, so I did a test. `time for i in $(seq 1000000); do echo 'adasfddfd09 dsassd90897 323sdsdsdsd sdddsdf56 dfdf45fdfdf'; done | sed 's/ /\n/g' > /dev/null` vs. `time for i in $(seq 1000000); do echo 'adasfddfd09 dsassd90897 323sdsdsdsd sdddsdf56 dfdf45fdfdf'; done | tr ' ' '\n' > /dev/null` On my computer, the variation between runs for either command is much higher than the difference between the two commands.

Comment: it would be nice if `awk` splits and matches in one line, but I can't find any solution. :(. Is there any test if `tr` or `sed` is faster? EDIT: Ha, two guys, same thought!

Comment: I always thought that the regex part of `sed` would be slower (and unnecessary here), but obviously I was wrong.

Comment: yeah i tested it on my system with your commands, too :). `sed` seems to be faster :D

Comment: You can use `gsub(" ", "\n")`, but I'm not sure how to combine it all into one command, as I presume that `awk` won't process these "just-split" lines separately anyway.

Comment: FWIW `time for i in $(seq 1000000); do echo 'adasfddfd09 dsassd90897 323sdsdsdsd sdddsdf56 dfdf45fdfdf'; done | awk 'gsub(" ", "\n")' > /dev/null` runs at similar times too. :)